# Getting .exe version information usng Ruby

Tags: ruby, windows, excel

I am using Windows 2008 Server, Ruby and win32ole to generate a test report in Excel. Once the report is generated, I would like the script to save the excel file with a name like TestReport_.xlsx.  If I right click on the executable for the software being tested and go to properties>details, I can see the build number I am looking to grab in the Product Version field.

I want to write a function that will return this build number so that, in Ruby, I can write something like.

```
build=GetBuildNumber()
SaveAsString="testReport_#{build}"
```

To be honest, I am kind of new to ruby, and if this is rather difficult its probably not worth doing.  It seems to me that since this information is somewhere in the executable, there might be a simple way to extract that information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is a ruby library for this, but you can use the Sigcheck command line tool.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897441.aspx

The following command would return the version only, you could call this from ruby.

```
sigcheck -q -n <file>
```

Comment: This seems like a potential solution! Thanks so much for the fast reply